# Fourier Transform of the differential equation $tf'' + 3f' + tf = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-transform

How do I fourier transform the differential equation 
$$tf'' + 3f' + tf = 0$$?
I.e I want the equation in terms of $\hat{f}$.

I think I'm able to use the scaling rule and differential rule on the middle term, but I can't figure out how to handle the terms $tf''$ and $tf$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$\mathscr{F}\{t^nf(t)\}(\omega)=i^n\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}\omega^n}\bigg(\mathscr{F}\{f(t)\}(\omega)\bigg)$$

Comment: Depending on how you defined the Fourier transform there might be some more constant flying around.

Comment: @JonasLenz I'm not sure about that, because there is the transform on both sides. But yes, it will appear in a lot of cases. I think it's ideal to put the constant to the inverse transform when you are applying it to a differential equation, because that would be in the way only (and also you could simplify with it anyway.)